# Where are the CCL IVideoCastConsumer onFailed status codes defined?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I need to know where are the `onFailed(int resourceId, int statusCode)` status codes defined at when implementing the `IVideoCastConsumer`?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html

Comment: That looked like the right list to me but I get a status code 1 which isn't anywhere in that list.

Answer (score 0):

The resourceId points to the "default" message available for the failure. Here is a list of (current) default resources (look in `res/values/strings.xml` in CCL); they can be overridden in your own project:

```
<!-- Failures -->
<string name="failed_to_connect">Could not connect to the device</string>
<string name="failed_setting_volume">Failed to set the volume</string>
<string name="failed_no_connection">No connection to the cast device is present</string>
<string name="failed_no_connection_short">No connection</string>
<string name="failed_no_connection_trans">Connection to the cast device has been lost. Application is trying to re-establish the connection, if possible. Please wait for a few seconds and try again.</string>
<string name="failed_perform_action">Failed to perform the action</string>
<string name="failed_status_request">Failed to sync up with the cast device</string>
<string name="failed_load">Failed to load media on the cast device</string>
<string name="failed_seek">Failed to seek to the new position on the cast device</string>
<string name="failed_receiver_player_error">Receiver player has encountered a sever error</string>
<string name="failed_authorization_timeout">Authorization timed out</string>
```

The second parameter, `statusCode` refers to the status code of the operation that you were perfroming; for example if you were calling `RemoteMediaPlayer.load(..)`, the `ResultCallback` provides a `MediaChannelResult` object that encapsulates a status code (can be obtained by `getStatus().getStatusCode()`). These status codes are mostly defined in  [CastStatusCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes.html). Note that sometimes there are no status codes.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will have to run through my code again but I can swear I sometimes get a fail status code of 1 which is not listed on that page.

Comment: If you get "1", let me know what operation is throwing that and what the resource is pointing to.

Comment: resourceId = 2131099723
statusCode = 1

Comment: I was trying to cast an m3u8 file without the allow origin header so it failed.

Comment: What api call caused that? What does that resourceId translate to (i.e. what is the string representation of it)?

Comment: The resourceid resolves to "Failed to load media on the cast device". I used `loadMedia(MediaInfo media, boolean autoPlay, int position)` on the VideoCastManager

Comment: For that api (and any other api from RemoteMediaPlayer), the statusCode is defined on that very same class and 1 refers to STATUS_FAILED: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer.html#STATUS_FAILED